# Why is the Marking Algorithm takes O(number of marks) ?

Tags: algorithms, string-matching

I am referring to the Marking algorithm defined in this article: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1602.00621.pdf

The Marking method is defined at the bottom of page 4 and has a pseudo code at the beginning of page 5.

In page 7 they claim "The runtime of the marking stage is O(B)". B being an upper bound for the number of marks of the marking algorithm.

To me It seems like the Marking algorithm should take O(|A|n), A being the positions in its input.

Can someone help me understand this?

Comment: Why can't it be both? Are you surprised that the complexity isn't $O(A \mid n)$ or that it is $O(B)$?

Comment: Notice O(B) is asymptotically less than O(|A|n)

Answer (score 1):

After mailing the author, I've found the answer:

The marking algorithm can be done in $O(B)$ by making sure that every unit of time we spend produces one mark. Consider the following piece of code:

```
for i in 1..|T|
  for j in A s.t. T[i]==P[j]
    m[i-j+1]++
```

The second loop need not take $O(|A|)$, it can be implemented more efficiently by precomputing the matching positions for every character in the alphabet. For example, if $T[i]$ happens to be '$c$' then we precompute all the offsets $j$ in $A$ for which `P[j]=='c'`. Then every iteration of the second loop produces a mark, like this:

```
for i in 1..|T|
  for j in offsets[T[i]]
   m[i-j+1]++
```

The total number of marks is $\sum_{a\in A} F_a=B$ because every position $a\in A$ has $F_a$ marks. So the run time is $O(B)$.